# fzf.vim - How to search git branch command with git log preview?

Tags: neovim, git, plugin-fzf, fzf

I'm trying to create neovim fzf command `FzfGBranches` to use `git branch -a` as query, and use `git log --oneline` as fzf preview:

```
command! -bang -nargs=0 FzfGBranches
            \ call fzf#vim#grep(
            \ "git branch -a", 1,
            \ fzf#vim#with_preview({
            \   'options': [
            \       '--prompt', '*Branches> ',
            \       '--bind', 'ctrl-d:page-down,ctrl-u:page-up',
            \   ],
            \   'placeholder': "echo {} | rev | cut -d'*' -f1 | rev | git log --oneline --graph --date=short --color=always --pretty=\"format:%C(auto)%cd %h%d %s\"",
            \ }), <bang>0)
```

When I call `FzfGBranches` command, it show up and seems good, but when I press `up`/`down` keys, the preview (on the right side) does not refresh. See below screenshot:

[image]

How should I specify the `--preview` option in fzf.vim?

Comment: `git log` doesn't accept revisions from stdin; perhaps you need `… | xargs git log …`?